# Basic questions on fopen, fwrite, fread in C

Tags: c

After I open the file using **fopen(file, "r")**, can I use **fwrite()** to the file or can I only use **fread()**?

After I open file using **fopen(file, "w")**, can I use **fopen(file, "a")** right away to switch the mode to append without using fclose() in-between?

Comment: What happened when you tried it? What does the documentation say?

Comment: The answer to both questions are no.

Comment: I'm not sure *why* you would want to do this; feels like it might be an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).. I suggest reading the manual pages for [fopen](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html), [fwrite](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fwrite.3.html) and [fread](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fread.3.html).

Comment: @Asteroids With Wings I tried and it seem to worked but I just wasn't sure if it was causing any problem that I couldn't see.

Comment: @Barmar I started opening the file with fopen( ,"w") then I used fopen again as ( ,"a") and it seemed to work fine. Could this cause any problem?

Comment: The first open will empty the file. The second open will append to that empty file. They don't really have anything to do with each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
It all depends on the mode which you have given
    mode    description
    r   opens a text file in reading mode
    w   opens or create a text file in writing mode.
    a   opens a text file in append mode
    r+  opens a text file in both reading and writing mode
    w+  opens a text file in both reading and writing mode
    a+  opens a text file in both reading and writing mode
    rb  opens a binary file in reading mode
    wb  opens or create a binary file in writing mode
    ab  opens a binary file in append mode
    rb+ opens a binary file in both reading and writing mode
    wb+ opens a binary file in both reading and writing mode
    ab+ opens a binary file in both reading and writing mode
```

For more info use the following link https://www.studytonight.com/c/file-input-output.php

Comment: I first opened the using "r" then I opened again using "w". Is this okay?

Comment: if you have to edit it, why don't you directly open it as "w+"..?